# What is the best way in Google Sheet to Count Unique, and summarize a value on the same row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently making a spreadsheet where people type in their name, and right next to it, a Value. This will then be sent over to another sheet that will Sort it,then summarize, and sort by name on how much they have earned. For Example:

Sheet 1

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Dave | 1 |
| John | 1 |
| Chloe | 5 |
| Dave | 1 |

Sheet 2

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Chloe | 5 |
| John | 3 |
| Dave | 2 |

Also, given the sum on Column B on Sheet 2, what is the best way to give someone a title based of their points? Lets say If you have 5+ points, you get Rank 3, 4-3 points are Rank 2, and below are Rank 1?

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rank 3 | Chloe | 5 |
| Rank 2 | John | 3 |
| Rank 1 | Dave | 2 |

I tried to do a mix with =UNIQUE and =SUMIF but it does not seem to work. Anyone have a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=sort(map(unique(tocol(A2:A;1));lambda(Σ;let(Λ;sumif(A:A;Σ;B:B);
      {ifs(Λ>4;"Big";Λ>2;"Medium";1;"Small")\Σ\Λ})));3;)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey there! I tested it out, and it could be me trying to convert it over to my Language excel (i.e "," isnt used to seperate, we use ";" because of Norwegian Google Sheet).

It seems to sort it sideways and not down like it worked for you.

Also, the Ranks are going to have entirely different string names (replace Rank 3 with Big, Rank 2 with Medium, and Rank 1 with small).

I am amazed at your knowledge! And id love if you could continue helping me :)

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1092391071604023318/1136753569391980738/image.png

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by creating a lookup table and then using a lookup function to retrieve the correct value.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Rank 1 |
| 2 | 3 | Rank 2 |
| 3 | 5 | Rank 3 |

```
=VLOOKUP(value,A1:B3,2)
```

A1:A3 contains the lower bounds and B1:B3 contains the corresponding rank.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TzqmCh2ndcTltlDqUQnsFOeOVga5bePwz4AaLKD5cDI/edit?usp=sharing) is a solution.

**Sheet1**

- Columns A:B are used to input the person's name and value.
- Columns D:F calculate the sum of value for each person (SUMIFS) along with their rank/title category (IFS).

**Sheet2**

- Used QUERY to pull each column and sort by the sum of value.